# can we have different return type of method in c# polymorphism

Tags: c#, polymorphism

is it possible in C# polymorphism that method will have different return type? I know polymorphism have different parameters but not sure about this

Comment: Are you actually talking about overloading or overriding? I would expect you to mean overriding (or implementing an interface) when you talk about polymorphism - but that doesn't include changing parameter types...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are referring to is *method overloading*; *not* polymorphism. And you can; with one caveat:

> Overloaded methods cannot differ **only** by the return type.

With polymorphism all parameters and the return type **must** match.

Method overloading occurs when you give two methods the same name:

```
public void MyMethod(string arg) { }
public int MyMethod(string arg, int arg2) { return 0; }
```

*Polymorphism* occurs when you override a base class function, but you *have* to keep the same signature:

```
public class A
{
    public void MyMethod(string arg)
    { }
}

public class B : A
{
    public override void MyMethod(string arg)
    { }
}
```

Comment: sir When I am putting one method with return type void and overloading it with other one with float return type I am getting error "not all code paths return a value". Why?

Comment: If there is no `return` statement in the `float` overload, you'll get that error. Just add `return 0` to the body (assuming its empty).

Comment: Languages like Haskell have "return value polymorphism".  It may be what OP is asking about.  In short, it's about a class having two methods `int foo(bool b)` and `List<T> foo(bool b)` which have the same name, the same parameters, but different return types.  The type system looks at how the result is used in order to determine which method must be called and with which type parameters.  This is a feature that I miss terribly in Python, C, C++ or C#.  I am currently trying to work on a way to implement such a thing in C#, but cannot promise success.

Comment: @Niriel Pretty sure that would be a relaxation of the restriction on overloads, not polymorphism, but I'll take your word for it that Haskell calls it that